# How to validate a string date with Ajax Control Toolkit (CalendarExtender)?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

> I have two TexBoxes that are formatted and get their text value by a CalendarExtender, and I would like to validate the first one greater than the second one; however, they are coming in as a string and not as date. How can I validate that? This is my asp code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="width:160px; text-align:center;" OnServerValidate="DateRange_ServerValidate"></asp:TextBox> 

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="width:160px; text-align:center;" OnServerValidate="DateRange_ServerValidate"></asp:TextBox> 

<asp:Label ID="lblDateError" runat="server"  ForeColor="#CC0000" ></asp:Label>

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"  Format="dddd, MMMM dd yyyy"
                TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupButtonID="Image1">                    
            </asp:CalendarExtender> 

            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" Format="dddd, MMMM dd yyyy"
                TargetControlID="TextBox2" PopupButtonID="Image4">                    
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

> In the code behind:

```
    protected void DateRange_ServerValidate(object sender, EventArgs args)  
{


    DateTime ToDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text.ToString(), "dddd, MMMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime currentdate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox2.Text.ToString(), "dddd, MMMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


    if (ToDate < currentdate)
    {
        lblDateError.Visible = true;
        lblDateError.Text = "End Date should not be earlier than the current date.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        lblDateError.Text = "";
    }

}
```

> Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's in the `DateRange_ServerValidate` method? Could you use `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert the string to a datetime?

Comment: I tried the code above, but it doesn't fire up. (Please see edit question)

Comment: How are you triggering your validation? Is there a submit button or something else?

Comment: Yeah, I got a save button. And, even after I save It, It doesn't trigger.

Comment: Could you show us the markup of the button? (i mean the .aspx part). Check if `CausesValidation` is true if `UseSubmitBehavior` is false. I think that when the button has submit behavior it automatically validates the page. And if i'm not mistaken, the page/control has to have AutoEventWireup set to true.

Comment: I follow your suggestion but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the comparevalidator and set the "Type" to "Date".

Like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="Textbox1"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ControlToCompare="Textbox1"  Operator="LessThan" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Type="Date"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Range"></asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="validate"/>
```

To validate this on the server you can just call

```
CompareValidator1.Validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt1;
DateTime dt2;
if (DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out dt1) && DateTime.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out dt2) && dt1 <= dt2)
throw new Exception("I do not like this.");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but it doesn't raise the exception.